# MongoDB Write Concern when Journaling is off

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, wiredtiger

I'm running mongo 3.4.7 (WiredTiger) replica set with two secondaries.

According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#replica-sets), when journaling is enabled and write concern is `{w: "majority", j: 0}`, the ack is sent after the data is written to "In memory".

However the docs don't specify what happens when journaling is *off* on the server (`--nojournal`). What happens in that case? What is the write concern waiting for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using MongoDB 3.4.7 with WiredTiger, there are certain defaults in place if you run MongoDB with the default values (journal is enabled):

- If newly created, the replica set would use protocol version 1 (see [Replica Set Protocol Versions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/replica-set-protocol-versions/))
- Default write concern is `{w:1}` (see [Write Concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/write-concern/))
- With `{w:'majority'}`, the default is `{j:true}` if journal is enabled as per default (see [writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault))

If you run MongoDB without journaling, using `{w:'majority', j:true}` will result in an error (see the Note section on [j option](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/write-concern/#j-option)):

```
[PRIMARY:replset] test> db.test.insert({a:1},{writeConcern:{w:'majority', j:true}})
WriteResult({
  "writeError": {
    "code": 2,
    "errmsg": "cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled"
  }
})
```

Please note that counter-intuitively, running WiredTiger with the `--nojournal` option may make it **slower**. This is because WiredTiger performs a [checkpoint](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/wiredtiger/#snapshots-and-checkpoints) every 60 seconds or 2 GB of data in MongoDB 3.4, and writes to the journal between checkpoints.

Disabling journaling will force any journal flushes to become a checkpoint instead. Since a journal sync is relatively lightweight compared to a full checkpoint, the forced checkpoints will slow down WiredTiger.

Comment: Thanks! Why does turning journaling off makes checkpoints more frequent? Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @Tzach I edited my answer to be more precise regarding this fact. It's currently not documented anywhere, but this behaviour in MongoDB 3.4.9 was defined in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.4.9/src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp#L242-L249

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question: Writing data change to disk.

When journaling is on, the first change is written to the journal, then it is written to data blocks.

Comment: Thanks! So when journaling is on, is the ack sent before or after the change is actually written to the disk?

Comment: Here is an image: http://bit.ly/2wZ6VkL at the situation where you have w:1, j:true, without journaling, of course, we have only written to the disk possibility. But, remember, even write is done to data blocks, actual write (flush) to physical disk happens later.

Comment: Do you have the same image for j:false and journaling off on the server?